# How to change color of items in SharePoint custom list

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, item, multi-select

The code I have it's used to change colors on a row in a custom list with a ribbon button when the ribbon button is pressed you got a dialog box comming upp with 4 buttons with 4 differt colors.

The problem is that i can only selecet one item at the time to change color but i want to select as many item i want, how do i do it? I use SharePoint online and Visual Studio 2013. The color code is in a seperate JS Link file.

This is the code:

```
'use strict';

var clientContext, hostweburl, parentContext, parentWeb, selectedItem, itemId, listId;

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
listId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListId"));
itemId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId"));
parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
parentWeb = parentContext.get_web();
selectedItem = parentWeb.get_lists().getById(listId).getItemById(itemId);


$(document).ready(function () {
clientContext.load(selectedItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFail);
});



function OnSuccess() {

$("#Blue").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'Blue');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

$("#Green").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'Green');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

$("#Red").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'Red');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

$("#Transparent").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'No Color');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

}


function OnFail() {
alert("Error");
}


function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
var params =
document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
        return singleParam[1];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to modifying the view of a list or it's items in SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint online recommended approach is to use JSLink and display templates..

[JSLink & Display Templates](http://curah.microsoft.com/73023/jslink-articles)

[JSLink and Display Templates Part 2 – Changing how individual fields display](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-2.html)

Comment: Not what i'm looking for Want to know how i can do changes to more then one item at the time

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below jquery in Script Editor web part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Open')");$Text.parent().css("background-color", "#FF9900");});
```

Comment: I dont want to use script editor want to do this in my code